# Is there a standard library function that parses integers like C# literal syntax?

Tags: c#, .net, integer

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types

> The type of an integer literal is determined by its suffix as follows:

> If the literal has no suffix, its type is the first of the following types in which its value can be represented: int, uint, long, ulong.

> If the literal is suffixed by U or u, its type is the first of the following types in which its value can be represented: uint, ulong.

> If the literal is suffixed by L or l, its type is the first of the following types in which its value can be represented: long, ulong.

> If the literal is suffixed by UL, Ul, uL, ul, LU, Lu, lU, or lu, its type is ulong.

The .Net standard library contains several functions for parsing string to integer with various kinds of options.

Is there any such function that will apply the above logic, or even part thereof, returning one of several integer types depending on suffix, magnitude or both?

Comment: How would you use such a method?

Comment: Echo Henk; I feel like I must chip in to opine that not only would this parsing method be fairly ugly, using it would probably be quite messy too. I think I'd just TrimEnd U/L and tryparse it as a long..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to your question (is there a standard function to parse C# integral literals) - the answer is no.

I'm not sure how they'd return the value they would be parsed. I went with a rather long tuple:

```
(bool succeeded, Type theType, int i, uint iU, long iL, ulong iUL)
```

This way, you get an indication of whether the parse succeeded (à la `int.TryParse`), and indication of what type of parse succeeded, and a way to get the value (no matter what type).

After that, I just went brute force, using a Regex to parse the parts of the input string.  By the way, I'm pretty sure that both `-234` and `+678` are valid integer literals; so I take care of the sign as well.

I start with the Regex pattern and the Regex:

```
private const string literalPattern = @"(?<prefix>[+-]?)(?<number>[0-9]+)(?<suffix>(ul|lu|u|l)?)";
private static Regex literalRegex = new Regex(literalPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

The `(?<name>pattern)` pattern allows for named groups.  You can see me using them in expressions like: `match.Groups["prefix"].ToString()` below.

Then I have my brute force parsing code:

```
 public static (bool, Type, int, uint, long, ulong) ParseIntegerLiteral(string theLiteral)
 {
     (bool, Type, int, uint, long, ulong) badReturn = (false, null, 0, 0, 0, 0);
     var match = literalRegex.Match(theLiteral);
     if (match.Groups.Count == 0)
     {
         return badReturn;
     }

     var negativeMult = 1;
     if (string.Equals(match.Groups["prefix"].ToString(), "-", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
     {
         negativeMult = -1;
     }

     Type type;
     var i = 0;
     var iu = 0U;
     var il = 0L;
     var iul = 0UL;

     switch (match.Groups["suffix"].ToString().ToUpper())
     {
         case "L": 
             type = typeof(long);
             if (!long.TryParse(match.Groups["number"].ToString(), out il))
             {
                 return badReturn;
             }
             break;
         case "U": 
             type = typeof(uint);
             if (negativeMult == -1)
             {
                 return badReturn;
             }
             if (!uint.TryParse(match.Groups["number"].ToString(), out iu))
             {
                 return badReturn;
             }

             iul = iu;

             break;
         case "UL":
         case "LU":
             type = typeof(ulong);
             if (negativeMult == -1)
             {
                 return badReturn;
             }
             if (!ulong.TryParse(match.Groups["number"].ToString(), out iul))
             {
                 return badReturn;
             }
             break;
         default:
             type = typeof(int);
             if (!int.TryParse(match.Groups["number"].ToString(), out i))
             {
                 return badReturn;
             }

             i *= negativeMult;
             il = i;
             if (i >= 0)
             {
                 iu = (uint)i;
                 iul = (ulong)i;
             }
             break;
     }

     return (true, type, i, iu, il, iul);
 }
```

As always, the code is very lightly tested.  You'll want to write some unit tests for it.

Answer (score 1):

A function can only have one return type, and since the different integral types are actually different dotnet datatypes, a single method that could return any of them can't exist... unless you were to get clever and return a composite object!  Something like:

```
public class CleverReturn
{
    public Object ParsedReturnValue { get; set; }
    public string ParsedReturnValueType { get; set; }
}
```

'ParsedReturnValueType' would contain the full namespace & type name of the type.  You could use that to create a variable of the correct type via reflection, and cast the ParsedReturnValue to it.  But I know of no such method in the .NET APIs.